# function not executing on first click

Tags: javascript

hello i have some code to mark an 'X' or an 'O' in a div for a tic tac toe game, but the function doesnt execute on the first click, it starts on the second click

I've look through other questions that have been asked 
but haven't found anything that is relevant to my code

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
function setX() {
    $('#container').on('click', function (e) {

        if (this !== e.target) e.target.textContent = 'X';

    });
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function setO() {
    $('#container').on('click', function (e) {

        if (this !== e.target) e.target.textContent = 'O';

    });
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

and this is my code to switch between functions each click

```
let myFunctions = [setO, setX, setO, setX, setO, setX, setO, setX, setO, setX, setO]
let nextFunction = 0;

function myFunctionSwitcher() {
    myFunctions[nextFunction]();
    nextFunction = nextFunction + 1;
}

container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myFunctionSwitcher();
    // whoWon()

});
```

Comment: Every single time, you are adding more events. meaning after you click 3 times, the container will run 3 functions. Track the X or O outside the event handlers.

Comment: When do you call `myFunctionSwitcher()`? There's no click handler until the first time you call that.

Comment: Don't change the click handler. Just use a global variable that says whether the current player is X or O, and toggle that variable in the function.

Comment: @Barmar i call it in this                                                  
   container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myFunctionSwitcher();
    // whoWon()
});    after i declare the function

Comment: So the first time you click, it calls `myFunctionSwitcher`. That adds a click handler that will be used the next time you click.

Comment: @JacksonMayhew That code should be in the question.

Comment: @Barmar my bad , just updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243043/function-not-executing-on-first-click/58243694#comment102858312_58243043), you're adding event listeners each click instead of setting a `X` or `O`. Without changing your current code too much you could do something like this:

```
function setX(element, event) {
  // don't set an onclick event here
  if (element !== event.target) event.target.textContent = 'X';
}

function setO(element, event) {
  // don't set an onclick event here
  if (element!== event.target) event.target.textContent = 'O';
}

let myFunctions = [setO, setX, setO, setX, setO, setX, setO, setX, setO, setX, setO];

function myFunctionSwitcher(element, event) {
    // pass the element and event forward to setO or setX
    myFunctions[nextFunction](element, event);
    nextFunction = nextFunction + 1;
}

$('#container').on('click', function (event) {
    // pass this and the event to myfunction
    myFunctionSwitcher(this, event);
    // whoWon()
});
```

You could make it yourself easier and instead do something like this:

```
// creates a toggle function toggling between `a` and `b`, starting at `a`
function toggleValues(a, b) {
  var toggle = false;
  return function () {
    toggle = !toggle;
    return toggle ? a : b; // ternary if
  };
}

const toggleOX = toggleValues('O', 'X');
$('#container').on('click', function (event) {
  if (this !== event.target) event.target.textContent = toggleOX();
  // whoWon()
});
```

Comment: yes, both blocks of code make sense to me and work well, thanks again, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

the way you are going about to problem is a little overcomplicated. You're basically switching the functions and adding more event listeners to the same thing.

Here's a small example that kind of does the X and O switching

```
$('#container').on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.textContent === "O"){
    event.target.textContent = 'X';
  } else {
    event.target.textContent = 'O'
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c5h2xkje/8/

the reason why your code only works on the second click is because at initialization, it has no eventListener for setting Xs or Os. You add the eventListener on the first click and then it know what to do afterwards.